# Magento2 - Attribute value not update while csv import

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to update the `additional_attributes` values from **csv** file in Magento2,the attribute name is : `manufacturer` and It have 30 values,and It's showing on product catalogue page in a drop down. So It's not updating the value,but another attributes updating fine.

So why this attribute value not updating?

I also tried with another Magento2 site but its working fine.

So what is the reason and why its not updating?

Comment: try to del that attribute from eav_attribute table and either increase module version or just remove module from setup_module table and run s:up again

Comment: Ok,lets see it work or not

Comment: yeah give it a try